# Powershell for loop throwing "the array index evaluated to null"

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops, powershell-core

For starters, I'm on Fedora 30 using PSCore version 6.2.1. I've encountered this issue in GNOME Terminal and the vscode snap.

I'm on the first challenge of the PSKoans module and I'm stuck when trying to use a for loop. I am given an array of strings, each of which is a collection of strings separated by commas.

```
$StockData = @(
    "Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close"
    "2012-03-30,32.40,32.41,32.04,32.26,31749400,32.26"
    "2012-03-29,32.06,32.19,31.81,32.12,37038500,32.12"
) # The array is much longer than that, but shortened for simplicity's sake
```

So, my idea is to build a hashtable out of each subsequent string line in the array by using the first string in the array as keys and each following line as a set of values. I'm using `-split` to split the values apart from within the strings. I want to use a for loop to iterate through the array and pull values, building a hastable in a file to be read later like so:

```
# Build the array of keys
[array]$keys = $StockData[0] -split ','
# Begin for loop, using $i as int
for ($i = 1, $StockData[$i], $i++) {
    # Create a text file for each hastable
    New-Item -Name "ht$i.txt" -ItemType File
    # Split current string into values
    $values = $StockData[$i] -split ','
    # Set value int
    $valuesInt = 0
    foreach ($key in $keys) {
        Add-Content -Path "./ht$i.txt" -Value "$key = $values[$valuesInt]"
        $valuesInt++
    }
}
```

As I run that, I get the following error:

```
Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.
At /home/user/PSKoans/Foundations/SolutionStockChallenge.ps1:28 char:6
+ for ($i = 1, $stockData[$i], $i++) {
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArrayIndex
```

I've looked it up and I find all kinds of scenarios in which people get this error message. I didn't really find a solid explanation for the error message the might lead me to an answer.

Reading the error message, it doesn't make sense to me. `the array index evaluated to null`...but the array index in the first case is `$StockData[1]` which is a valid index and should return $true and continue with the loop. Am I missing something?

Comment: you splitting using `,` but I think the list having no comma between items , Iam not sure though

Comment: I'm splitting on individual strings, so really I'm splitting `"Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close"` so it splits each part of the whole string due to commas in the string.

Comment: try to print out what the list has , I think you will get an empty list

Comment: I think you're missing the `[0]` index which dictates that I am acting on the first string of the array, not the whole array its self. Within `$StockData[0]`, which is a string, there are commas. When I use `-split ','` it splits up the string into multiple strings because there are commas present in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of your `for` loop is wrong. The `for` loop uses semi-colons as separators.

```
for ($i = 1, $StockData[$i], $i++) {
```

should be

```
for ($i = 1; $StockData[$i]; $i++) {
```

Comment: Bingo! That's embarrassing, ha. Thanks for reading through my question and the quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

ConvertFrom-Json in PowerShell Core has the coolest switch - AsHashTable. Try this:

```
$StockData | convertfrom-csv | convertto-json | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable
```

Comment: That is very neat and I may end up using that as a part of my solution to the Koan challenge, however it doesn't really answer my specific question.